# Lambda expressions with external immutable variables used within the expression

Tags: java, lambda

I have this example code that I've written specifically for this question, but it reflects a real scenario I was confronted with at work:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("ALICE", "Alice", "BOB", "Bob", "CHUCK", "Chuck");

Predicate<String> has_u_or_i_whenLowercased = Stream.of("u", "i")
        .map(bit -> (Predicate<String>) (source -> source.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).contains(bit)))
        .reduce(Predicate::or)
        .orElse(p -> false);

List<String> english = names.stream()
        .filter(has_u_or_i_whenLowercased)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(english);
System.out.println(english.size());
```

It creates a predicate that checks if the source String contains `u` or `i` when lowercased with the English locale (**EDIT:** *There are a dozen better and simpler ways to implement this, but this is just an example. In the real scenario I am filtering a small data set based on an arbitrary number of search criteria*). I'm going to use this lambda expression across several methods of a class.

Now, assume I want to have a different locale, which will be passed as an argument to the method that will use the lambda expression (not the constructor). At work, it's not a Locale I have to deal with, but I defined its boundary as being an immutable variable.

The simplest solution I could think of was to have a method "build" that lambda expression.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    List<String> names = Arrays.asList("ALICE", "Alice", "BOB", "Bob", "CHUCK", "Chuck");

    List<String> english = names.stream()
            .filter(createUIPredicate(Locale.ENGLISH))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(english);
    System.out.println(english.size());

    System.out.println("--");

    List<String> turkish = names.stream()
            .filter(createUIPredicate(new Locale("tr", "TR")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(turkish);
    System.out.println(turkish.size());
}

private Predicate<String> createUIPredicate(Locale locale) {
    return Stream.of("u", "i")
            .map(bit -> (Predicate<String>) (source -> source.toLowerCase(locale).contains(bit)))
            .reduce(Predicate::or)
            .orElse(p -> false);
}
```

However I feel like there is something wrong with this approach. If I am injecting an external immutable variable into a functional interface, I thought maybe I'm supposed to pass it as an lambda expression argument instead somewhere?

When confronted with a lambda expression which has an external immutable variable used within the expression, and that immutable variable may be different for every use within a stream intermediate operation, is there a specific approach that matches a known functional programming pattern?

Comment: The implementation for the Predicate is overkill and should not use any `Stream` stuff. It could be simply `s -> Pattern.compile(".*u|i.*").matches(s.toLowerCase(locale))`. MUCH easier to understand and reason about.

Comment: @Clashsoft ``".*[UIui].*"`` is even easier.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass it as an lambda expression argument"? I think your solution is perfectly reasonable. (But a bit overdone in other respects as other commentors have pointed out before). Sure you could simplify the whole thing even more by packing everything into one method and call it like this: `List<String> turkish = filterUI(names, new Locale("tr", "TR"))`

Comment: @Clashsoft You are right, but please ignore what that example performs. This example is an unrelated problem I came up with while writing this question, and really I didn't have much inspiration. In the real implementation I am filtering a small data set based on an arbitrary number of various search criteria; one Predicate per criteria (I used to run a for loop to filter on each Predicate, before I switched to building a single Predicate that encompass them all).

Comment: @martinhh `Function<String, Predicate<String>> predicateBuilder = external -> s -> s.contains(external);` versus `String external = ...; Predicate<String> predicate = s -> s.contains(external);` The lambda expression only uses variables that are on the left side of the arrow `->`. Somehow I feel like using variables that are external to the lambda expression is a hidden form of coupling or dependency, but I'm most likely wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really much practical difference between your method solution and your lambda solution from the comments, both take advantage of lambdas "closing over" "effectively final" variables. Both are pretty common in the Java 8 functional code I've written.

```
private Predicate<String> build(Locale locale) {
  return str -> str.toLowerCase(locale);
}
```

versus:

```
Function<Locale, Predicate<String>> build = locale -> str -> str.toLowerCase(locale);
```

The decision between the two is just one of style preference and/or whether that builder is used only within a single method or in multiple places in your class.